# How to parse json string in c#

Tags: c#, json, .net, parsing, .net-core

How can i parse a json string in c# controller

```
public ActionResult GetAjaxSession(string search)
{
...
}
```

Variable which containt the json string :

```
search
```

The Json string :

```
[{"id_employe":"35"},{"id_employe":"80"},{"id_employe":"136"},{"id_employe":"140"}]
```

I want to get all id_employe from the string

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: im not parsing to an object, your documentation is not helping me

Comment: You have to parse to an object first before you can retrieve the data, unless you plan to parse this thing by hand.  If the idea of having DTOs bothers you, use `dynamic`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But parsing would be the right way, to get the right data out of your string. 
Example with using Newtonsoft.Json:

```
var objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObj>>(jsonText);
```

With the class:

```
public class MyObj
{
    public string id_employe { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: +1 and big thanks

2 days im trying and searching how to do this, your example unstuck me, you really help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Malior's approach is perfectly fine, it's a typed approach. I'd like to mention an alternative way, using Linq and dynamic:

```
var jsonText="[{\"id_employe\":\"35\"},{\"id_employe\":\"80\"},"
             +"{\"id_employe\":\"136\"},{\"id_employe\":\"140\"}]";
var objects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(jsonText);
var values = objects.Select(s=>s.id_employe).ToList();
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9Zxuie)

This will create a list, so `values` contains the following elements:

> 35,80,136,140

Because it is dynamic, you don't need to declare an extra class. 
Note that both approaches will throw a `JsonReaderException` if there is anything wrong with the JSON string (e.g. missing `[` etc.). And if the property name isn't found it can throw a `RuntimeBinderException` - so you should use a `try ... catch` block.